# How do I update a react component with API data

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component that is trying to show a set of tasks, for this it's getting all the tasks he needs to display from redux.

But once the component is loaded, the component should check on the backend if some of these tasks were actually done (the point is to automatically check, avoiding manual check when possible). To achieve this the component :

- load data from a set of API end points (currently I'm doing this from componentDidMount)
- than display the data to the user
- than try to see if there was an update to each task shown
- if there was an update and a task was done, than send an API request to mark the task as done and update the component after that

I don't know in terms of structure where things should go, especially the task update part.

Any suggestion welcome !

Answer (score -1):

Why you store your tasks in redux, it's easier for you to store all your task with property isFinishshed, and you will have your tasks and you will know are they finished. If you can mark the tasks as done in your app you will have put or post API call, and after that you will again call the get API for tasks.(Or you will get them in response at your put/post).